# Annotation driven Spring 2.5 MVC not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying out a very simple Spring MVC which only displays a welcome message.

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
 <display-name>courtannotation</display-name>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/courtannotation-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>courtannotation</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>courtannotation</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My bean configuration file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.springrecipes.court.web" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>    
</beans>
```

My Controller - WelcomeController is as follows:

```
package com.apress.springrecipes.court.web;

import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome.htm")
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    public WelcomeController() {

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        Date today = new Date();
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "today", today);
    }
}
```

In WEB-INF lib I have following jar files:

1. spring.jar
2. spring-webmvc.jar
3. spring-context.jar
4. spring-context-support.jar

In the classpath I have servlet-api.jar.
I am using spring 2.5.5, Eclipse Indigo, Spring IDE plug-in for eclipse,java 1.6, windows XP, jBoss-5.1.0.
http://localhost:8080/courtannotation/welcome.htm leads to [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/courtannotation/welcome.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'courtannotation'.
My welcome.jsp is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title><spring:message code="welcome.message" text="Welcome to Court Reservation System"/></title>
</head>
<body>
<fmt:formatDate value="${today}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
</body>
</html>
```

My message.properties is as follows:

```
welcome.title=Welcome
welcome.message=Welcome to Court Reservation System
```

What I am missing here? Pls help.

Comment: Are http://localhost:8080/welcome.htm available?

Comment: Are you deploying to the `courtannotation` context? Oh, that's what php-coder is asking, basically.

Comment: I am deploying to the courtannotation context.

Comment: Try adding this <context:annotation-config/> in your context file

Comment: I deployed the same web application in Tomcat6(had to add some jars  in WEB-INF/lib like commons-logging.jar,standard.jar,jstl.jar)& voila it works! So now somebody need to help me in cracking the mystery why it works in Tomcat & does not work in jBoss.